# String "contains"-slicing on Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

How can I slice a MultiIndex by its string content? I.e. whether that particular index contains a certain string?

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'ab', 'b'], 
                   'c': ['d', 'd', 'd'], 
                   'val': [1, 2 , 3]}).set_index(['a', 'c'])

In [13]: df

Out[13]:

val
a   c   
a   d   1
ab  d   2
b   d   3

In [15]: df.xs('a', level='a', drop_level=False)

Out[15]:

val
a   c   
a   d   1

In[16]: df.xs(contains('a'), level='a', drop_level=False)
```

Expected output:

```
Out[16]: 

a   c   
a   d   1
ab  d   2
```

Obviously that last bit is not possible.

- How can this be done elegantly?
- Can you do it case-insensitive in some way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (df.index.get_level_values('a'))
Index(['a', 'ab', 'b'], dtype='object', name='a'

print (df.index.get_level_values('a').str.contains('a'))
[ True  True False]

df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values('a').str.contains('a', case=False)]
print (df1)
      val
a  c     
a  d    1
ab d    2
```

Comment: Thanks! Quite a mouthful…

Answer (score 3):

Another method is to use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

> The DataFrame.index and DataFrame.columns attributes of the DataFrame
> instance are placed in the query namespace by default, which allows
> you to treat both the index and columns of the frame as a column in
> the frame.

```
>>> df.query('a.str.contains("a")') 
      val
a  c     
a  d    1
ab d    2
```

which IMO is a little more readable and succinct than

```
>>> df[df.index.get_level_values('a').str.contains('a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

***When index level is not critical***, an alternative is to use `df.filter(...)` with regular expressions; super helpful when exploring data by either column or row. For example, this will give you the same answer with a bit less code:

`df.filter(regex=re.compile('A',re.I),axis=0)`

[image]

However, this filters at all index levels, `df.filter(regex=re.compile('D',re.I),axis=0)` will look at index "c" and it show this:

[image]